# RTSP Redirection to another client (RFC related)

Tags: c#, media, rtsp, rfc

I'm currently implementing the RTSP standard in C# (server/client), but after re-reading the RFC 2326 a thousand times, there is still one thing that's unclear to me.

It looks like RTSP is just a [C<->S] control protocol. But what if I'm trying to build up a management for several client/server devices in a network? Example:

I have a management application that is a RTSP client. I'd like to tell an another client that he should connect to a different server. Something like:

```
SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.12 RTSP/1.0
      CSeq: 302
      Transport: RTP/AVP;rtsp-redirect:192.168.1.155
```

The RFC is very strict on the transport property. I also considered "REDIRECT", but this is only S->C for e.g. load balancing usages.
Is there a way to achieve a client <-> client communication for redirection (e.g. for telling a client he has to drop a command on another server?)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is aggregate anyway... You wouldn't want to redirect the public to a camera behind a company firewall... You would want to first setup the camera on a Media Server and then allow access to whomever via the Media Server by password protecting the stream on the Media Server.

Check out my implementation in c# which is compatible with VLC @ https://net7mma.codeplex.com/ and supports all of what I mentioned above!

There is a CodeProject article here -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

And actually there is ..

@ http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt

10.10 REDIRECT

A redirect request informs the client that it must connect to another
   server location. It contains the mandatory header Location, which
   indicates that the client should issue requests for that URL. It may
   contain the parameter Range, which indicates when the redirection
   takes effect. If the client wants to continue to send or receive
   media for this URI, the client MUST issue a TEARDOWN request for the
   current session and a SETUP for the new session at the designated
   host.

This example request redirects traffic for this URI to the new server
   at the given play time:

```
 S->C: REDIRECT rtsp://example.com/fizzle/foo RTSP/1.0
       CSeq: 732
       Location: rtsp://bigserver.com:8001
       Range: clock=19960213T143205Z-
```

If you need anything else let me know!

Comment: Hi @Jay If all I want to do is a redirect, is there a way to do that your MMA project? I just want to set up a ton of redirects for RTSP streams.

Comment: Yes, you could do that in a variety of ways, I would probably use a custom handler though, there are examples in the Unit Tests of just about everything.

Comment: Has anyone seen the REDIRECT working properly after the unicast stream has already started ? It seems to be a real problem, while the spec does not elaborate on that case.

Comment: It's up to the server to handle it correctly... I have not experienced such issues with redirect that I have perceived a problem with the RFC as of yet in that regard... If you elaborate a bit more I can try to help